# Docker-compose failing on startup

Tags: docker-compose

I am running

```
docker-compose version 1.25.4, build 8d51620a
```

on

```
OS X Catalina, v10.15.4 (19E266)
```

I am using the system python.

When I run docker-compose, it crashes with the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 72, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 128, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1077, in up
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1073, in up
  File "compose/project.py", line 548, in up
  File "compose/service.py", line 355, in ensure_image_exists
  File "compose/service.py", line 381, in image
  File "site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 17, in wrapped
docker.errors.NullResource: Resource ID was not provided
[9018] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

I have tried a fresh repo clone and a fresh install of docker, neither work. What could be causing this?

Comment: It sounds like, but it is unclear, that you are trying to run it from the source code by doing something along the lines of `python setup.py install`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It turned out that I had uninitialized environment variables that were causing the crash.

The particular cause was the env vars setting image names in the docker-compose file and then trying to pull a blank image.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: I'm not sure what the interaction was, but the compose file was looking for some environment variables that were not set.

Comment: On my case, I had this error due to `image: $ENV_VAR` on base compose, and not defining the env var, defining a `build:` map on next override file, ending up with `image: ''` and blowing it up

Comment: Same here, empty ENV VAR was the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

It can be initialized environment variables but for my case, it was some other command before docker-compose build which was failing.

- I was pulling images from the registry but it could not find them.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this error when passing docker-compose files explicitly and omitting one. e.g.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up # fails
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.override.yml up # works
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced with the same issue.
In my case, it was different.

I had 2 docker-compose files:

- docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
networks:
  web: {}
```

- docker-compose.development.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    image: ""
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      API_URL: http://example.com/api
    ports:
      - "11000:22000"
    networks:
      - web
    restart: on-failure
```

The problem was from `image` property in `docker-compose.development.yml` file.

When I removed it & ran the below command:

```
docker-compose --project-name my-web -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.development.yml up --detach
```

It was successful.
This is the new `docker-compose.development.yml` file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      API_URL: http://example.com/api
    ports:
      - "11000:22000"
    networks:
      - web
    restart: on-failure
```

Comment: You were having the same issue as everyone else, just your image key was blank for a different reason.

Comment: But in the previous version of Docker, my command ran successfully (I don't remember exactly, it was around version 20)